# Disable autoComplete in AutocompleteInput at react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, admin-on-rest

**In general question: How to add custom `autocomplete` value to the `AutocompleteInput` ?**

**Problem started** when you will try to add options to the AutocompleteInput:

```
<ReferenceInput source="company_id" reference="companies" validate={required()}>
        <AutocompleteInput optionValue="id" optionText="name" options={{autoComplete: 'blabla'}}/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

[image]

Everything works good with (for example):

```
<LongTextInput options={{autoComplete: 'blabla'}}/>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve exactly, not how ?

Comment: @GildasGarcia I trying to find solution "how to disable google chrome autoComplete" at react-admin fields.